# how to share audio element among several pages in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a website with an index page which only:

- contains an iFrame
- launches an audio player and starting to play tracks.

The different links are open in the iFrame, so I hide everything under index.html.
I create the audio player via the line:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio");
```

I am confused with the scoping.  I want to access this audio variable from other documents which will open in the iFrame.
Is there a way to store this audio element so any page can access it?  Or is there a function allowing to retrieve it by type, like `getElement('audio')` ?

My only goal is start playing music on one page, and be able to control it from another (to be able to call `audio.play()` and `audio.pause()` from another.

Comment: Why don't you keep it in the parent page and control it using the frames?

Comment: Agreed. It's just a scoping issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using frames and you would like to control a single element, then you can declare the element and access it using `parent.` object. So, you have the:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio");
```

Above code in the `index.htm` and in each of the page, you can use:

```
parent.audio.play();
parent.audio.pause();
```

**Note:** This works only if both the frames are from the same domain.

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by accessing the parent document context and getting the audio element from there.

In the parent

```
// Method 1
var audio = document.createElement('audio')
audio.id = 'my-specific-audio'
document.body.appendChild(audio)
// Method 2
window['my-audio-key'] = audio
```

In the child

```
// Method 1
var audio = window.parent.document.getElementById('my-specific-audio')
// Method 2
var audio = window.parent['my-audio-key']
```

One caveat: both frames must be of the same origin (domain). The browser does not allow cross-origin context access.